# Multiply two placeholder with different rank in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two placholders with the following dimensions

```
x_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None, 4])
```

and

```
y_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None, 4, 3])
```

I want to multiply each element of `x` with one row of `y_ph` to get an output of shape `(None, 4, 3)`.

Example of output I am looking,

```
x = np.random.uniform(-1,1, (2,2))
z = np.random.uniform(-1,1, (2,2,3))
x, z

([[ 0.27083503, -0.13795923],[ 0.8436118 ,  0.00771057]])

([[[ 0.51905276,  0.01173655, -0.57335926],
[ 0.42347431, -0.05438272,  0.21042366]]
[[ 0.91347706, -0.28086164,  0.54952429],
[ 0.41551953, -0.6207727 ,  0.32066292]]]))
```

I want to do following operation:

```
result = np.zeros((2,3))
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        result[i] += x[i,j]*z[i,j,:]
print(result)
[[ 0.08215548  0.01068127 -0.18431566]
 [ 0.77382391 -0.2417247   0.46605767]]
```

Any way to do it in tensorflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one dimension at the end of `x_ph` so you can use broadcasting to multiply both tensors:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
x_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None, 4])
y_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None, 4, 3])
result = tf.expand_dims(x_ph, -1) * y_ph
```

Comment: Thanks, it works well, but I had to add tf.reduce_sum(result, axis=1)

Comment: @AlirezaMoradzadeh Ah okay, I thought you wanted the output with shape `(None, 4, 3)`.